# "...Окружённое с четырёх сторон крытой колоннадой"; колоннада, относящаяся к одному пространству, возможна во мн. ч.?

Tags: грамотная-речь, редактура

> Перисти́ль — открытое пространство, как правило, двор, сад или
>   площадь, окружённое с четырёх сторон крытой колоннадой. Википедия

Меня смущает число ***колоннад***...

> Только после того, как Рим ближе соприкоснётся с Грецией, с её
>   культурой, он внесёт новшество в устройство своего жилища: появится и
>   второй внутренний двор – *перистиль*. Этот образованный колоннадами
>   открытый, светлый, утопающий в зелени сад со второго века до нашей эры
>   глубоко полюбится Риму, и он станет неотъемлемой частью его частной
>   жизни, олицетворением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ряд, один ряд колонн, если быть точным, — уже колоннада. Была бы упомянута ориентация по стороне горизонта такого ряда, такое («колоннадами») здесь стало бы логично; но если ряды колонн одного характера замкнуты по периметру, лучше использовать ед. ч.
2. Со второго века до нашей эры: со II века до н. э.

Answer (score 3):

Из "Справочника строителя", о старинном патио в Гренаде:

> Сад расположен обособленно на террасах, **ограничен колоннадами**
>   башен, дворцов, стенами.

http://www.baurum.ru/_library/?cat=equipping_territory&id=4161

Мне кажется неудачным причастие в сочетании "*образованный* колоннадами": колоннады не могут быть *элементами* сада.

Comment: Конечно же, сад, образованный колоннадами, — нонсенс. Однако о перистиле в том же справочнике: "Новый элемент озеленения - внутренний дворик (перистиль) с бассейном и **колоннадой.**" (ед. ч.!)

Answer (score 2):

> Этот образованный колоннадами открытый, светлый, утопающий в зелени сад со второго века до нашей эры глубоко полюбится Риму, и он станет неотъемлемой частью его частной жизни, олицетворением.

1. О коллонадах

> КОЛОННАДА, -ы; ж. [франц. colonnade] Ряд колонн (1 зн.), несущих **общее перекрытие**. К. Казанского собора в Санкт-Петербурге. Дом соединён с флигелями сквозными колоннадами ([Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0&all=x))

Таким образом, если нет общего перекрытия, то имеем несколько колоннад.

2. О местоимении *он*

Формально *он* — о Риме.
Исправление: **...глубоко полюбится Риму и станет...**

3. Есть ли у Рима частная жизнь?

*Его частная жизнь* (о Риме) — допустимо ли? Варианты: просто *частная жизнь*, *частная жизнь римлян*, *частная жизнь его жителей*.

4. Олицетворение без указания чего

Просто *олицетворение* — некорректно. См:

> 3. **чего**. Воплощение идеи, понятия, каких-л. свойств, качеств в человеческой личности. Мать - о. доброты. Плюшкин - о. скупости. Венера - о. женской красоты ([Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?all=x&word=%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))

Если этот сад олицетворяет частную жизнь римлян, то вариант исправления: **станет неотъемлемой частью частной жизни, ее олицетворением**.